# NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/Versioned using Jackson JSON parser

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a Spring MVC REST project and I am being given the following message when I try to build the application:

> NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/Versioned

I believe this is to do with the implementation of Jackson's JSON parser in the application but I am using:

```
 jackson-annotations-2.4.0.jar 
 jackson-core-2.4.1.jar
 jackson-databind-2.4.1.jar
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This class is part of the `jackson-core-asl.jar`  include it in the classpath.

Comment: it happened to me to. I use maven so I added the artifact jackson-core-asl following your answer, but I still get this error. Any more suggestions?

Comment: @Avision the same error? which Version of jackson-core-asl.jar do oyu add?

Comment: It's now fixed. I'm writing here in case any more people encounter it. It turned out that Jackson was already imported into my project as a dependency for a different artifact (Hadoop), which imported version 1.8. I needed version 1.9.13. SOLUTION - Excluded jackson-core-asl and jackson-mapper-asl to the Hadoop dependency definition.